# VSCode no longer showing text suggestions

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

I was happily using VSCode for my SQL (jinja) coding.
Then, it stopped suggesting words/text in the intellisense suggestions for things like my variable names, functions, CTEs, tables etc.
The suggestions are still working - they are giving suggestions for one of the extensions in the workspace...
[image]

In the picture above, you can see it is still working, but not giving me "page_view_count" as a suggestion, as I have 'page_view_count' just before it.
Strange thing is that this feature seems to be working fine when I work in other folders. I've tried restarting VSCode multiple times.

Please help, I dont know how to get this fixed.

Comment: I've never used VSCode. But check this post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68263285/how-to-trigger-inline-suggestion-in-vscode]

Comment: Thnx, but that is not what I am looking for. That seems to be for code block suggestions. I am rereferring to the built in intellisense suggestions.